# Laravel 5.3 get last insert id after registration

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5.3

Using laravel5.3
php 5.6.3

I want the last inserted id in users table for the redirected page after registration

So I want the last inserted id to userprofileadd.blade.php

I have also tried  ->with('id', $user->id) from register function

I don't want automatic login after registration , so I removed the login part , and after registration the user will be redirected to another form  , and i want the latest user id (who ever registered) from users table

Register controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\role;
use App\Userdetails;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/userprofileadd';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'hr']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [

            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'role'=>'required'
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'role_id'=>$data['role'],
        ]);
    }

    public function showregistrationform()
    {
        $roles = role::all(); // get all teams
    return view('auth.register', [ 'roles' => $roles]);
    }
}
```

register function (i have commented out login after registration)

```
 public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

       // $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
            // ->with('id', $user->id)
    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Why did you comment out the login after registration?

Comment: i don't want automatic login after registration , so i removed the login part , and after registration the user will be redirected to another form  , and i want the latest user id who ever registered from users table

Comment: Check my answer and see if that solves your problem or it maybe gives a general idea of what you should do.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using model then

```
$user = new User();
$user->name = "JOHN";
$user->save();
$user->id; // contain the inserted id
```

if you are using db class

```
$id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
   ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

Answer (score 2):

**To get the last created user**

```
$user = User::create([

    'email' => $data['email'],
    'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    'role_id'=>$data['role'],
]);

$this->lastCreatedUserId = $user->id;
```

**To pass the userId to custom redirection page**

You may use the `Laravel Auth  redirectTo method`. [Doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/authentication#included-authenticating).

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    return route('customroutename', ['id' => $this->lastCreatedUserId]);
}
```

Example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\role;
use App\Userdetails;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    public $lastCreatedUser;

    use RegistersUsers;

    protected $redirectTo = '/userprofileadd';

    //The redirectTo method will take precedence over the redirectTo attribute.
    protected function redirectTo()
    {
        //assuming your route name is 'userprofileadd' if not, use your route name of the route('/userprofileadd')
        return route('userprofileadd', ['id' => $this->lastCreatedUser]);
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware(['auth', 'hr']);
    }

    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [

            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
            'role'=>'required'
        ]);
    }

    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        $user = User::create([

            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'role_id'=>$data['role'],
        ]);

        $this->lastCreatedUser = $user->id;
        return $user;
    }

    public function showregistrationform()
    {
        $roles = role::all(); // get all teams
    return view('auth.register', [ 'roles' => $roles]);
    }
}
```

You can access the last created user in your UserprofileController's index method like,

```
public function index($id)
{
    $lastCreatedUser = $id;
    //you may pass this variable to the view
}
```

Hope it helps.. Let me know the results..

Comment: yes my route :

Route::get('/userprofileadd', 'UserprofileController@index');

Comment: @shank does my answer works? Or do you have any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for or not, but you can do this to retrieve the latest record in the users table:

```
$latestUser = App\User::latest()->first();
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: actually I can get the latest id with your answer , but I want to send it in the url and capture it in a hidden field in the next form

Comment: Why don't you feed it to the view you're redirecting to, and in that view you can capture in the hidden field like this {{ $user->id }} ?